# issue in creating new flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I need help. i am new to flutter. while creating new project in android studio flutter, system is prompting an error that "project creation error, flutter create command was unsuccessful" and when run flutter doctor it shows nothing

how to sort it out?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: attach a screenshot of the problem